# Bootstrap 4 Carousel Scale different sizes images not working properly

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-plugins, carousel

I try to make bootstrap responsive carousel with different size (height/width) which may be different each time

so what I did I make simple bootstrap carousel and try to include the jquery-scale plugin but it won't works with this

here is my code

```
[Codepen][1]
```

https://codepen.io/md-shareque/pen/VJXNxX

Answer (score 0):

you can try this.

`<img class="scale" data-scale="best-fill" data-align="center" src="https://www.tamkein.com/uploads/header_images/k2(2).png" alt="Los Angeles" class="responsive">`

add this **class="responsive"** class, your every img tag.